# FomData is always empty with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I got a strange problem i can't figure out since hours..
I use FormData object in JS to handle my forms, i use it in other pages and bring no problem.
In this specific page, the formData stays empty regardless of I declare one manually or dynamcally with the form as a parameter.

Here is my JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        function handleFormSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var ApiKey = '{{ Config::get('bts.apiKey') }}';
            var ApiUrl = '{{ Config::get('bts.api') }}';

            var url = ApiUrl + 'content/user/reminder';

            var form = this,
                formData = new FormData(form);

            var test = new FormData();
            test.append('test', 'fuck u');
            console.log(test);

            console.log(formData);
            if ($(form).data('loading') === true) {
                return;
            }

            $(form).data('loading', true);
            formData.append('key', ApiKey);

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'post',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                error: function (data) {
                    swal('Error', 'The distant server cannot be reached', 'error')
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                       console.log('ok');
                    } else {
                        console.log('nope')
                    }
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $(form).data('loading', false);
                    $(form).trigger('reset');
                },
                dataType: 'json'

            });

        }

        $('#complianceForm').on('submit', handleFormSubmit);
    });
```

I'm using laravel 4 but there is no link between my prob and that 'cause it works on another page with the almost the same code.

About my HTML, this just basics inputs, i don't even have an input of type file.

Here is my form opening :

```
<form method="POST" action="/manage/234/content/87/3/access" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="complianceForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

If someone knows why, any help would be very appreciated ^^

Comment: Did you open the console and check for errors, it looks like the variables `ApiKey` and `ApiUrl` are syntax errors `?

Comment: Checked, no errors on the console.

Comment: `var form = document.getElementById('complianceForm');`..  I lol'd at the profanity in your debug output.

Answer (score -2):

it should be like this:

```
var form = this;
formData = new FormData($(form));
```

you can try this one, if above one not worked:

```
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('complianceForm'));
```

update the code, and try again

Comment: got this error : TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement.

Comment: Surely `FormData` does not accept a jQuery object? Using `this` inside the jQuery event handler would get the native element, which is what the OP wants, there's nothing wrong with those lines of code.

Comment: OK just arrived at the office this morning and tried again.. Works perfectly withtout i change anything in my code...